# LINQ expression is not being translated to SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to achieve a compiled SQL query from LINQ which will check if `query` is substring of any of three columns in database (case insensitive).

**I'm using .NET Core 1.1**

Query that I come up with is as follows:

```
users.Select(u => new
  {
    User = u,
    query = u.FirstName.ToLower() + u.LastName.ToLower() + u.Email.ToLower()
  }).Where(x => x.query.Contains(query))
```

But when looking at debug informations I am getting this warning:

> The LINQ expression '(([u].FirstName.ToLower() + [u].LastName.ToLower()) + [u].Email.ToLower()).Contains(__query_0)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

Second query that I tried:

```
 users.Where(x => u.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(query) || u.LastName.ToLower().Contains(query) || u.Email.ToLower().Contains(query))
```

but it gives me exactly the same warning.

Why is is the case?
I am looking for something like:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE FirstName LIKE query OR LastName LIKE query OR Email LIKE query
```

**UPDATE**

I did one more experiment :

```
    users.Where(u =>
    u.FirstName.Contains(query) ||
    u.LastName.Contains(query) ||
    u.Email.Contains(query));
```

And this also resulted in

> The LINQ expression '(([u].FirstName.Contains(__query_0) OrElse [u].LastName.Contains(__query_1)) OrElse
>   [u].Email.Contains(__query_2))' could not be translated and will be
>   evaluated locally.

Comment: If your database collation is `xxx_CI` you don't need the `.ToLower()`. `SELECT CONVERT (varchar, SERVERPROPERTY('collation'));` to verify.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. However I think (maybe I am mistaken) that when my query is not compiled to SQL it will be case sensitive.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not compiled"? If you run the same query for Linq2Objects than yes it would act differently. (Case sensitive)

Comment: Note that your querying method has flaws (which you may or may not care about). For a user named John Nyman, you will create a query like `johnnymanjohn.nyman@company.com`. If the user is looking for "Johnny", he will get a hit on John Nyman, even though "Johnny" does not occur in either the first name, last name or email. Also note that you get different results if you swap the order of concatenation: putting the last name first (`nymanjohnjohn.nyman@company.com`) suddenly yields no hits for "Johnny".

Comment: @Flater that is true! Thank you, I do care about that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is because `.ToLower()` and `.Contains()` are functions in the string class and cant be translated to SQL by the linq provider.
All queries (unless explicitly specified) will follow the database collation, and if it is `CI` it is Case Insensitive and you do not need the `.ToLower()`.
As for `.Contains()` you need to use entity function `Like`.

```
users.Where(u =>
    EF.Functions.Like(u.FirstName, "%" + query + "%") ||
    EF.Functions.Like(u.LastName, "%" + query + "%") ||
    EF.Functions.Like(u.Email, "%" + query + "%"));
```

However this seems to be added in EF core 2.0. For 1.1 I dont think there is any way to do it. I would recommend skipping EF and writing plain old SQL directly.

Comment: Does this hold true even if part of query is evaluated locally?

Comment: No, the part that is linq2Object would be Case Sensative. I would suggest you do a `.AsEnumerable()` to specify that some part of the query should be local.

Comment: This I understeand. However this does not answer my original question: why above LINQ query is not being translated to SQL.

Comment: That is because the linq provider can not translate `.ToLower()` as it is a function in the string class.

Comment: Cant translate `.Contains()` either, you need to use entity function `Like`.

Comment: Does `EF.Functions` exists in EF core for dotnet core 1.1? If so, what  I need to include in my project?

Comment: I think it was added to Core 2.0. There a lots of features missing in EF Core compared to EF 6. See https://blogs.msmvps.com/ricardoperes/2016/09/05/missing-features-in-entity-framework-core/ for details.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will +1 your answer. Maybe someone have a method for 1.1

Comment: As it turned out there is no way to do this in 1.1. I migrated my project to version 2 and used your logic.